# mysql group_concat problem: ISNULL replaces null values but in the incorrect order

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat, coalesce, isnull

When using **GROUP_CONCAT**, the **ORDER BY** clause appears to works correctly.  However, when replacing **NULL** values using **ISNULL** or **COALESCE**, although the actual values are in order, the **NULL** values all end up at the beginning of the concatenation (see below). How do I get my **NULL** replacement values to be in the correct column order so they properly represent the values being replaced.

```sql
SELECT filledForm.creationDate AS date, GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(answers.answer, "NULL") ORDER BY answers.promptID) AS answers
FROM filledForm
JOIN prompts ON filledForm.formID = prompts.formID AND prompts.formID = 100
LEFT JOIN  answers ON prompts.promptID = answers.promptID AND filledForm.filledFormID = answers.filledFormID
GROUP BY filledForm.filledFormID;
```

using some sample data this gives:

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| date                | answers                                                         |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2023-03-10 14:21:03 | NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,bob,2023-03-16,English                 |
| 2023-03-11 02:28:23 | NULL,NULL,NULL,John Smith ,60,test2@get.com,2023-03-24,German |
| 2023-03-11 02:32:41 | NULL,NULL,Tom,22,tom@testURL.com,2023-03-29,11:00,English     |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

instead of:

```
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| date                | answers                                                         |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2023-03-10 14:21:03 | bob,NULL,NULL,2023-03-16,NULL,English,NULL,NULL                 |
| 2023-03-11 02:28:23 | John Smith,60,test2@get.com,2023-03-24,NULL,German,NULL,NULL |
| 2023-03-11 02:32:41 | Tom,22,tom@testURL.com,2023-03-29,11:00,EnglishNULL,NULL      |
+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which can be seen when I run the query without the group by portion:

```sql
SELECT answers.answer AS answers
FROM filledForm
JOIN prompts ON filledForm.formID = prompts.formID AND prompts.formID = 100
LEFT JOIN  answers ON prompts.promptID = answers.promptID AND filledForm.filledFormID = answers.filledFormID
ORDER BY filledForm.filledFormID, prompts.promptID;
```

```
+-------------------+
| answers           |
+-------------------+
| bob               |
| NULL              |
| NULL              |
| 2023-03-16        |
| NULL              |
| English           |
| NULL              |
| NULL              |
| John Smith        |
| 60                |
| test2@get.com     |
| 2023-03-24        |
| NULL              |
| German            |
| NULL              |
| NULL              |
| Tom               |
| 22                |
| tom@testURL.com |
| 2023-03-29        |
| 11:00             |
| English           |
| NULL              |
| NULL              |
+-------------------+
```

or perhaps more easily understood with a few more columns showing:

```sql
SELECT filledForm.filledFormID, prompts.promptID, answers.answer AS answers
FROM filledForm
JOIN prompts ON filledForm.formID = prompts.formID AND prompts.formID = 100
LEFT JOIN  answers ON prompts.promptID = answers.promptID AND filledForm.filledFormID = answers.filledFormID
ORDER BY filledForm.filledFormID, prompts.promptID;
```

```
+--------------+----------+-------------------+
| filledFormID | promptID | answer            |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+
|           14 |        9 | bob               |
|           14 |       10 | NULL              |
|           14 |       11 | NULL              |
|           14 |       12 | 2023-03-16        |
|           14 |       13 | NULL              |
|           14 |       14 | English           |
|           14 |       15 | NULL              |
|           14 |       16 | NULL              |
|           15 |        9 | John Smith        |
|           15 |       10 | 60                |
|           15 |       11 | test2@get.com     |
|           15 |       12 | 2023-03-24        |
|           15 |       13 | NULL              |
|           15 |       14 | German            |
|           15 |       15 | NULL              |
|           15 |       16 | NULL              |
|           16 |        9 | Tom               |
|           16 |       10 | 22                |
|           16 |       11 | tom@testURL.com   |
|           16 |       12 | 2023-03-29        |
|           16 |       13 | 11:00             |
|           16 |       14 | English           |
|           16 |       15 | NULL              |
|           16 |       16 | NULL              |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+
```

These are the full tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE prompts (
    promptID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    formID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (formID)
        REFERENCES form (formID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,        
    hash VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    prompt TEXT(1023) NOT NULL,
    changeDate TIMESTAMP
    UNIQUE(formID, hash)
);


CREATE TABLE filledForm (
    filledFormID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    formID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (formID)
        REFERENCES form (formID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    creationDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT (UTC_TIMESTAMP),
    INDEX (formID)
);

CREATE TABLE answers (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    filledFormID INT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (filledFormID)
        REFERENCES filledForm (filledFormID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    promptID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (promptID)
        REFERENCES prompts (promptID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,    
    answer TEXT(99999),
    INDEX (filledFormID)
);

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to `ORDER BY answers.promptID` which is on the righthand side of your `LEFT JOIN`. `ORDER BY prompts.promptID` instead.

```
SELECT
    f.creationDate AS date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(a.answer, "NULL") ORDER BY p.promptID) AS answers
FROM filledForm f
JOIN prompts p ON f.formID = p.formID AND p.formID = 100
LEFT JOIN answers a ON p.promptID = a.promptID AND f.filledFormID = a.filledFormID
GROUP BY f.filledFormID;
```